# Kendo-UI - Creating a Dynamic Form via JSON

Tags: json, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

I have been able to successfully build out a dynamic form using JSON and Kendo.Observable, however I cannot initialize the dropdownlist values successfully within the same JSON.  The only way I can get it to work is by binding the dropdown lists to a separate json request after creation.  See the example below....

Here is an example of some JSON that works (no dropdown list)

```
{"fields": [
                {"name" : "FirstName", "label" : "First Name", "type" : "text", "css" : "test"},    
                {"name" : "LastName", "label" : "Last Name", "type" : "text", "css" : "test"},
                {"name" : "Email", "label" : "Email", "type" : "text", "css" : "test"},
                {"name" : "Phone", "label" : "Phone", "type" : "text", "css" : "test"},
                {"name" : "Subscribed", "label" : "Subscribed", "type" : "checkbox", "css" : "test"}
                ]}
```

Here is an example where I have added a dropdown, not going to post the whole thing, I have tried a number of different variations on the below to try and populate the select but can't find any that work

```
 {"fields": [
                {"name" : "Email", "label" : "Email", "type" : "text", "css" : "test"},
                {"name" : "FirstName", "label" : "First Name", "type" : "text", "css" : "test"},
                {"name" : "LastName", "label" : "Last Name", "type" : "text", "css" : "test"},
                {"name" : "Company", "label" : "Company", "type" : "text", "css" : "test"},
                {"name" : "ddlCountry", "label" : "Country", "type" : "select", "dataTextField" : "text", "dataValueField" : "value", "dataSource":[{"text" : "AF","value" : "Afghanistan"},{"text" : "AL","value" : "Albania"},{"text" : "DZ","value" : "Algeria"},{"text" : "AS","value" : "American Samoa"},{"text" : "AD","value" : "Andorra"},...etc...
```

and here is the script to bind it

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/go/getformjson",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (model) {
           // convert the JSON to observable object
            var viewModel = kendo.observable(model);
            // bind the model to the container
            kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please provide JSFiddle for same?

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle of a working form without a dropdown http://jsfiddle.net/SKmX6/32/

Comment: I have gotten much closer on this, however the only outstanding bit is why the dropdown is displaying [Object] instead of the text.  Updated Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/aUAJv/64/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the data-text-field and data-value-field attributes:

```
<select data-bind="source: options" data-text-field="ddltext" data-value-field="ddlvalue" />
```

Here is updated version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aUAJv/64/

Comment: @Atanas Korchev I use your answer.. In some cases in my application it returns an error in the console "Uncaught ReferenceError: ddlvalue is not defined ".. sometimes it works sometimes not. is there anything I should take care?