# Kendo-UI - Dynamic Form via JSON Multiple Dropdown Lists

Tags: javascript, dynamic, kendo-ui, ddl, dynamic-forms

I am aware that there is similar question at [Kendo-UI - Creating a Dynamic Form via JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145505/kendo-ui-creating-a-dynamic-form-via-json)
what if I do have multiple ddl in same dynamic form with the same options. Lets say I have "from city" and "to city" ddl's dynamically added to the form, how am I going to get the selected values separately?

Comment: What have you tried? And what is your issue?

Comment: The issue is; form elements are defined by the end user and the number of input fields and dropdown lists are not predictable. I tried to data-bind the id and/or name attribute for the select node as in input nodes but it throws an error that these attributes can not be binded dynamically.
<input data-bind="attr: { type: type, name: name, class: css}"/> is used to bind dynamic name for input field and could be read like 
$("#example input").each(function () { values += $(this).attr("name") + ": " + $(this).val(); });
how this can be done for select fields?